# After upgrading to SignalR 2.0.2 the .NET 4.0 client became slow

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I was migrating our servers and client code to SignalR 2.0.2 from SignalR 1.1. Mostly the server/client code remain unchanged but upgrading to the latest version caused slowness on receiving messages. For comparison I use the SignalR 1.1 .NET 4.0 client with a server using the latest (2.0.2) SignalR libraries, with this configuration I don't see the slowness.

The .NET client code looks like this

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection(uri, "sessionCode=" + sessionCode);
hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SessionHub");
hubProxy.On<string>("onMessageReceived", HandleWebMessageReceived);
hubConnection.Start(new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.LongPollingTransport()).Wait();
```

We use SignalR in our response system, that has .NET client and JS client. The typical flow of a message is the JS client sends a response, the server then propagates it to the .NET client, then the .NET client sends an ack back to the server, that gets propagated back to the original JS client.

When sending a message back to an individual JS client the code looks like this

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = hubProxy.Invoke("SendToIndividual", json, connectionId).Wait();
```

So I use fiddler to see what's the difference between these version of SignalR .NET 4.0 client. For brevity I'm just going to post partial request header.

With SignalR 1.1 client the sequence looks like these:

```
POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=UAcJHRiStwmX%2BXQ
POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=UAcJHRiStwmX%2BXQ
POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=UAcJHRiStwmX%2BXQ
POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=UAcJHRiStwmX%2BXQ
```

With SignalR 2.0.2 client the sequence looks like these:

```
POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name
POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name
```

*/signalr/poll* means we received data from the server (response from JS client), */signalr/send* is when we send an ack back.

From the log above it seems that we receive another response before we ack the first message. So I added the ServerGotRequest and GotResponseHeader session timer on fiddler to verify the timing of the messages. (I wanted to post an image but I don't have enough *reputation* to post an image.)

```
ServerGotRequest  GotResponseHeaders
13:48:52:265      13:49:05.235         POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
13:49:05.256      13:49:33.196         POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
13:49:05.274      13:49:05.277         POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name
13:49:33.199      13:50:00:972         POST /signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=KK4Nkpe%2BG0
13:49:33.206      13:49:33.219         POST /signalr/send?transport=longPolling&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name
```

When viewing the timestamp it seems everything is in order but fiddler is logging it differently. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a requirement for LongPolling? Have you compared performance using WebSocket?

Comment: Our windows app is build with .NET 4.0, when I didn't specify any transport, it will use SSE but it's still slow. I also build our app with .net 4.5 with signalr client and it still slow.

Comment: They all show the same symptom. I also debug this on the server and JS client, when the JS client sends a response, and the .NET client sends an ack, the ack message reach the JS client almost instantaneously but the invoke on the .NET client took a while to complete.

Comment: Is it just starting the connection that has slowed down? If so, can you add your SessionHub.OnConnected method to your question? The first /poll response sent to the 2.0.2 client is likely a message indicating to the client that OnConnected completed on the server. Until this message is received, the 2.0.2 client will not complete the Task returned from hubConnection.Start.

Comment: Oh, crap when I move the code that gets executed onMessageReceived  `hubProxy.On<string>("onMessageReceived", HandleWebMessageReceived);` to a different thread, it's fast again.